# What's the benefit of using async to return data from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I've been reading a lot on WebApi2 and I really like it, however I just don't understand why every method is using `async` instead of standard methods.

Here is the example:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(BookDto))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBook(int id)
{
    BookDto book = await db.Books.Include(b => b.Author)
        .Where(b => b.BookId == id)
        .Select(AsBookDto)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (book == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(book);
}
```

What's the benefit here? I will still need to wait for my book to be loaded from db using ef before serving it. Does this somehow differs from regular way where I don't use tasks to retrieve book?

Comment: Excellent question (and a good answer from Stephen Cleary)...  I was thinking the same!  I couldn't understand why you'd use these Tasks with async, then call them, and *wait* for the reply.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On the server side (e.g., WebAPI), `async` methods allow the request thread to return to the thread pool while the database server is generating the response. This allows you to scale better.

When the database server returns the response to your WebAPI method (i.e., the task returned by `FirstOrDefaultAsync` completes), then ASP.NET will grab another thread from the thread pool and resume processing your request.

Note that not *every* method should be `async`. You should only use `async` when you want to `await` some operation. There's a [great Channel9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET) that describes the concepts and benefits of using `async` on ASP.NET. I also gave a talk at [ThatConference](http://www.thatconference.com/) this year on [`async` on the server side](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/slides-available-thatconference-2013.html) (link to my blog post including slides).

Comment: But while server waits for task completion - this task is using some other thread do perform it's job. Aren't we just moving job from thread 1 to thread 2?

Comment: @Dmitry: No. I have a blog post that explains [why there isn't a thread being used](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).